# Can OneTimeWorkRequest and PeriodicWorkRequest be used together?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I use the WorkManager and I have one Worker, and I run it periodically at 1 hour intervals. But in some special cases, can I run this Worker with OneTimeWorkRequest?
Would it end the PeriodicWorkRequest if I did it this way?

What is the best method to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same Worker class in two different WorkRequest:

```kotlin
val oneTimeWorkRequest: WorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>()
       .addTag("OneTime")
       .build()

val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
      .addTag("Periodic")
      .build()

val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(myContext)
workManager.enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest)
workManager.enqueue(periodicWorkRequest)
```

You can then use [getTags()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#getTags()) in your Worker, if you need, to detect which WorkRequest is currently executing.